# I receive information from an api with axios and the result is a mixture of string and json objects, how can I read this?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

The json examples is: `{"code": 200, "message": "", "response": {"bvcc": [Object], "financiero": [Object], "ibc": [Object], "industrial": [Object]}, "success": true}`   how i read with javascript, i try with this code but show me an error the first time (Error: "Cannot read property 'bvcc' of undefined")

My code in React Native:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: token
      }
    };

    setModalVisible(true);
    const indexQuery = async () => {
      const urlIndices = baseUrl + "/mercado/indices";
      await axios.get(urlIndices, config)
      .then((res1) => {
        setBvcMonto(res1.data.response.bvcc.PRECIO_ULT);
        setBvcUltVarRel(res1.data.response.bvcc.ULT_VAR_REL);
        setBvcVolumen(res1.data.response.bvcc.VOLUMEN);
      })      
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error:"+error);
      });
    };
    indexQuery();
  }, [token]);



When i try JSON.stringify(res1) show me the error.    Thanks in advance
```

Json complete:

```
{"config": {"adapter": ["xhr", "http"], "data": undefined, "env": {"Blob": [Function Blob], "FormData": [Function FormData]}, "headers": [Object], "maxBodyLength": -1, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "get", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "transitional": {"clarifyTimeoutError": false, "forcedJSONParsing": true, "silentJSONParsing": true}, "url": "https://bolsadecaracas.com/api/mercado/indices", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}, "data": {"code": 200, "message": "", "response": {"bvcc": [Object], "financiero": [Object], "ibc": [Object], "industrial": [Object]}, "success": true}, "headers": {"access-control-allow-headers": "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization", "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "cache-control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate", "connection": "Keep-Alive", "content-length": "614", "content-type": "application/json", "date": "Sun, 19 Mar 2023 07:18:40 GMT", "expires": "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT", "keep-alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "keepalive": "on", "keepalivetimeout": "15", "maxkeepaliverequests": "100", "pragma": "no-cache", "server": "Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.3.12", "vary": "User-Agent", "x-powered-by": "PHP/7.3.12"}, "request": {"DONE": 4, "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2, "LOADING": 3, "OPENED": 1, "UNSENT": 0, "_aborted": false, "_cachedResponse": undefined, "_hasError": false, "_headers": {"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "authorization": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjE3IiwibmFtZSI6IkFwcEJWQyIsImVtYWlsIjoiZGFuaWxvLmJ2Y0Bib2xzYWRlY2FyYWNhcy5jb20ifQ.kvWlkRVV1KgtBOO5zrAA53kqSk_HZLi0WqeYPTwz2VU"}, "_incrementalEvents": false, "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {"access-control-allow-headers": "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization", "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "cache-control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate", "connection": "Keep-Alive", "content-length": "614", "content-type": "application/json", "date": "Sun, 19 Mar 2023 07:18:40 GMT", "expires": "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT", "keep-alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "keepalive": "on", "keepalivetimeout": "15", "maxkeepaliverequests": "100", "pragma": "no-cache", "server": "Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.3.12", "vary": "User-Agent", "x-powered-by": "PHP/7.3.12"}, "_method": "GET", "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://bolsadecaracas.com/api/mercado/indices", "_performanceLogger": {"_closed": false, "_extras": [Object], "_pointExtras": [Object], "_points": [Object], "_timespans": [Object]}, "_requestId": null, "_response": "{\"success\":true,\"response\":{\"bvcc\":{\"COD_SIMB\":\"BVCC\",\"PRECIO_ULT\":\"2.6\",\"PRECIO_APERT\":\"2.75\",\"ULT_VAR_REL\":\"-5.45\",\"VOLUMEN\":\"2326\"},\"ibc\":{\"TIPO_INDI\":\"I\",\"INDI_ACTUAL\":\"28833.84\",\"INDI_CIE\":\"0\",\"DIF_PRECIO_CIE\":\"0\",\"PORC_DIF_CIE\":\"0\",\"INDI_MAX\":\"29414.69\",\"INDI_MIN\":\"28763.66\"},\"industrial\":{\"TIPO_INDI\":\"S\",\"INDI_ACTUAL\":\"13893.6\",\"INDI_CIE\":\"0\",\"DIF_PRECIO_CIE\":\"0\",\"PORC_DIF_CIE\":\"0\",\"INDI_MAX\":\"14143.5\",\"INDI_MIN\":\"13650.5\"},\"financiero\":{\"TIPO_INDI\":\"F\",\"INDI_ACTUAL\":\"52514.3\",\"INDI_CIE\":\"0\",\"DIF_PRECIO_CIE\":\"0\",\"PORC_DIF_CIE\":\"0\",\"INDI_MAX\":\"53836.34\",\"INDI_MIN\":\"52513.27\"}},\"code\":200,\"message\":\"\"}", "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_subscriptions": [], "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_url": "https://bolsadecaracas.com/api/mercado/indices", "readyState": 4, "responseHeaders": {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate", "Connection": "Keep-Alive", "Content-Length": "614", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Date": "Sun, 19 Mar 2023 07:18:40 GMT", "Expires": "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT", "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5, max=100", "KeepAlive": "on", "KeepAliveTimeout": "15", "MaxKeepAliveRequests": "100", "Pragma": "no-cache", "Server": "Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.3.12", "Vary": "User-Agent", "X-Powered-By": "PHP/7.3.12"}, "responseURL": "https://bolsadecaracas.com/api/mercado/indices", "status": 200, "timeout": 0, "upload": {}, "withCredentials": true}, "status": 200, "statusText": undefined}
```

and i try get the bvcc values

When run first time that is my error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please Share the error message.

Comment: Done, thanks anyway, I solved it with this:   setBvcMonto(res1.data.response.bvcc['PRECIO_ULT']);

Comment: Just add in this format  res1.data.response.bvcc['PRECIO_ULT']   and works

Comment: You should not mix and match async await and then. Use either async await OR then.

Comment: not, show me this error, if not use .then  =>   Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):

Comment: RubenSmn Your comment helped me, I changed my call to fetch instead of get and it was resolved

Answer (score 0):

if response is like this

```
{"code": 200, "message": "", "response": {"bvcc": [Object], "financiero": [Object], "ibc": [Object], "industrial": [Object]}, "success": true}
```

Then try accessing

```
res1.response.bvcc
```

Comment: but how i access the bvcc object?    when restart not work,  i use res1.data.response.bvcc['PRECIO_ULT']  and work only when save this component but when restart fail again

Comment: the json complete is this into final the question

Comment: Alright try to parse it first using JSON.parse method

Comment: not,  i have this error when use JSON.parse by all sentence =>  Error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'bvcc' of undefined